# What is the difference between Network Manager and 'ifconfig' 'ifup', etc?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ifconfig

Ubuntu seems to provide at least two network "toolsets" (for lack of a better term). I'm running into conflicts between these two.

- [Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)
- Something which is more like the [traditional network tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html) (e.g. ifconfig, 'ifup', [/etc/network/interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man5/interfaces.5.html)

I am often running into conflicts between these different sets of tools. For example, I'm running Ubuntu Desktop at home and I'm using software like KVM/libvirt which recommends that I [disable Network Manager](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Debian.2FUbuntu_Bridging), but disabling Network Manager causes other things to break.

What is the difference between Network Manager and the traditional network tools? Can these two suites run side-by-side or must I stick with one or the other? Is there a document which summarizes the difference between these different tools? I have been unable to find one.

(Forgive the vagueness of this question. I've searched and searched for an answer, but I have only found many vague answers which don't seem relevant to Ubuntu 10.04/Lucid, and I may not fully understand the purpose of NetworkManager. However, this seems to be a frequently asked question. If you have advice for clarifying this question, please post a comment.)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`NetworkManager` and `ifconfig` are not (by default) compatible (`NetworkManager` won't configure interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`). `NetworkManager` is a sort of settings daemon that makes sure that multiple users can edit network connections, this is very smart in a desktop environment (especially on laptops that might move around between different wireless networks). Basically `NetworkManager` is a frontend to `iproute`, `dhclient`, `wpa_supplicant` and `ppp`.

`ifconfig` is a general tool for configuring network interfaces, you can for example do like this:

```
ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 hw ether 10:10:10:10:10:10
ifconfig eth1 down
```

to set your IP, netmask and MAC address of `eth1`, and then down (disable/turn off) your interface. `ifconfig` doesn't read any config files and does only exactly what it is told.

`ifup` and `ifdown` are helper programs that use `ifconfig` to configure a network interface in accordance to `/etc/network/interfaces` this will make sure that if there are any up, down, pre-up, pre-down, post-up, post-down scripts that need to be run they will be.

Ok, then there is `wpa_supplicant` and `dhclient`. `dhclient` is a DHCP client - `ifup` will use this if a network interface is configured for DHCP, as will `NetworkManager`. `wpa_supplicant` is a tool for configuring encryption on wireless networks.

Most of these tools have man pages, for instance the interfaces-file have it's own manpage that describe the format of that config file.

```
man interfaces
man ifconfig
man ifup
```

So that being said i would recommend that you remove (or disable) `NetworkManager`, I don't think that any thing will break from removing `NetworkManager` except the gui tools for setting up network. If you want to configure wireless without `NetworkManager` you might want to look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=263136).

Comment: ps: For any interface (eth0, wl0,...), you can select one of ifconfig and NetworkManager freely. Which interface was managed could detaile by `nmcli device`.

Answer (score 9):

On a typical Debian-based distribution you have two command-line utilities used to configure network interfaces: the deprecated [`ifconfig`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/net-tools/ifconfig.8.fr.html) from [`net-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/net-tools) and the newer [`ip`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/ip.8.en.html) from [`iproute2`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2).

However these two utilities directly configure the kernel and do not persist your config, if you reboot your machine you will need to reconfigure your interfaces again.

You have three major packages available for that purpose:

- [`ifupdown`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown)
- [`NetworkManager`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager)
- [`systemd`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/systemd) and its daemon `systemd-networkd`

In general, you should choose one and stick to it, even if `ifupdown` works well with `NetworkManager` it can still creates unexpected configuration issues.

### `ifupdown`

Quite deprecated but reliable, you might encounter it on many older systems. The config is stored in `/etc/network/interfaces` and managed by the `networking.service` daemon which is a wrapper around the [`ifup`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/ifup.8.en.html) and [`ifdown`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/ifdown.8.en.html) commands which are also wrappers themselves around `ifconfig` (or `ip` for [`ifupdown2`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown2)).

Read the man at [`ifupdown`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html).

### `NetworkManager`

Usually included with desktop distributions since many graphical front-ends are available, the config is stored in `/etc/NetworkManager` and managed by the `NetworkManager.service` daemon.

You can manage the config with the included [`nmcli`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager/nmcli.1.en.html) or [`nmtui`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager/nmtui.1.en.html) utilities.

Read the man at [`NetworkManager`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/network-manager/NetworkManager.8.en.html).

### `systemd-networkd`

Usually used on server distributions and the official successor to `ifupdown` as it is included within `systemd`, the config is stored in `/etc/systemd/network` and managed by the `systemd-networkd.service` daemon.

Read the man at [`systemd-networkd`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd-networkd.8.en.html).

### `dhclient`

Although not a daemon, [`dhclient`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/isc-dhcp-client/dhclient.8.en.html) from [`isc-dhcp-client`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/isc-dhcp-client) is nonetheless a very important package and often required on desktop distributions as you often need to obtain a IPv4 from a DHCP server.

Hopefully, as IPv6 (which uses [SLAAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration)) is slowly being adopted, this will probably change in a near or distant future.

Comment: concise and very well explained. Now if you just add a table that would be awesome.

Answer (score 6):

These toolsets are complementary, not mutually exclussive.

FWIW, `ifconfig` is just a tool among other `*config` tools which are used to configure network interfaces.

The `ifup(8)` and `ifdown(8)` tools are one layer above the `*config` tools. You can think of them as helper tools.

Likewise, NetworkManager is a level above the `ifup(8)` and `ifdown(8)` tools. For lack of a better term, NetworkManager is able to *orchestrate* the tools(ets) from the levels below in order to acomplish higher level tasks like Internet Connection Sharing with additional ease compared to just using the tools from the levels below.

Comment: If you would like additional details leave a comment and I will oblige.

Comment: @Li Lo: Yes please provide additional details. I thought that ifup/ifdown would modify hosts in /etc/network/interfaces , and Network Manager would ignore any interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces. (See question "d. Why won't Network Manager manage my Networks? " under [FAQ/Common issues/Pitfalls](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager0.7#FAQ/Common%20issues/Pitfalls)

Comment: Ehm, ifup/ifdown use /etc/network/interfaces, and are separate from NetworkManager. NetworkManager does not mess with /etc/network/interfaces at all, except for by default reading a list of interfaces to ignore.

Comment: Downvoted this answer since it's been called out as plainly wrong and there's no response from the poster. So I assume the accusation is true.

Answer (score 1):

Network Manager is a GUI program used when dealing with Ubuntu as a workstation OS installed on your desktop/laptop.

The ifconfig-type utilities are command-line based and are used when dealing with Ubuntu as a server OS, when you don't have a graphical interface available to you (for example, when you boot up an Amazon EC2 instance based on Ubuntu). They are typically used over an ssh connection.

Comment: Yes, I once used the `ifdown` command over an ssh connection. It didn't work out too well for me.

Comment: Network Manager is not just a GUI. There is also a network-manager daemon, which is a different package then the network-manager-gnome GUI applet. What is the difference between network-manager and the traditional networking tools?

Comment: NetworkManager runs on top of wpa-supplicant which is /another/ tool for configuring networking.  /etc/network/interfaces can make calls to wpa-supplicant as well

Comment: IN fact NetworkManager is not a gui-only-tool. you can use it with the commandline, too.

Comment: This Answer is just wrong. `ifconfig` is just a old tool for networking.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove network manager I assume you need to configure /etc/network/interface to make interfaces work.