# What could cause "Waiting for network configuration" + 2 minutes unskippable hanging at boot when no network interfaces are configured?

Tags: boot, networking, network-manager, init.d

After installation of a bunch of unknown programs (the program causing the problem must have been in the long list of dependencies, `/var/log/dpkg.log` contains > 38000 entries for the relevant dates) my system (Ubuntu 14.10 amd64 with Linux 3.17.7) hangs at boot at the entry ~`Waiting for network configuration
Waiting 60 more seconds for network to become available` (I didn't find the message with `grep -r -I "Waiting for" /var/log/ && grep -r -I "waiting for" /var/log/"` which is ridiculous, but state of the art as it seems).

I know that this message and behavior occur if interfaces are managed in `/etc/network/interfaces` and/or `/etc/network/interfaces.d/`and not available at boot time, but they're empty. `network-manager` has been disabled to start according to `rcconf` by one of the installed packages and I reenabled it there which didn't change anything.

I don't understand why even an under average programmer can't print `Starting the_service_name
Waiting for network configuration
Waiting 60 more seconds for network to become available` rather than the above error message and/or (at least) properly integrate with different system logging facilities (and no, it's no my duty to set it up properly when a default configuration can be guessed and created perfectly)...

**EDIT 1:** Before the issue occured, all network connectivity has been handled by `network-manager` and that's the way it should be after the issue is fixed. I just realized that the `network-manager` service isn't started during boot although set up to be started in `rcconf`. I didn't have to start it manually before the issue occured.

**EDIT 2:** I just realized that I - as underaverage system administrator - installed version 11.0-79.1-2 of `chkconfig` from a deb package which possibly crashed `init.d` and/or `upstart`. Can that be undone without reinstalling the system?

**EDIT 3:** After reinstalling the system the issue reappeared after installing and/or removing the following packages (`dpkg` log to be replaced with something readable after askubuntu.com/questions/566964/how-to-get-a-list-of-newly-installed-packages-after-time-x-without-removed-packa is answered):

```
Start-Date: 2014-12-30  01:43:12
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get install python-augeas
Install: python-augeas:amd64 (0.4.1-2)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  01:43:19

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  01:43:22
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get autoremove
Remove: libecore-x1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libecore-fb1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libopenvg1-mesa:i386 (10.4.0~git20141112.7a82961b-0ubuntu0ricotz), libecore-evas1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libecore-imf1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libeeze1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libeina-dev:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libecore-file1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), x11proto-print-dev:amd64 (1.0.5-2), libevas1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libmount-dev:amd64 (2.25.1-3ubuntu4), libecore-ipc1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libevas-loaders:amd64 (1.8.1-2build1), libeio1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libemotion1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libxp-dev:amd64 (1.0.2-2), libeet-dev:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libfribidi-dev:amd64 (0.19.6-1), libecore-input1:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1), libevas-dev:amd64 (1.8.6-2ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  01:43:29

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  01:55:43
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get install twine
Install: python3-pkginfo:amd64 (1.1-2~ubuntu14.10.1, automatic), twine:amd64 (1.3.1-1~ubuntu14.10.1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  01:55:47

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  02:42:27
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Install: libmouse-perl:amd64 (2.3.0-1build1, automatic), libclass-singleton-perl:amd64 (1.4-1), heirloom-mailx:amd64 (12.5-2), libghc-dpkg-prof:amd64 (0.0.3-4build6), python-smartpm:amd64 (1.4-2), libc6-armhf-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.105), dwww:amd64 (1.12.1, automatic), libio-interactive-perl:amd64 (0.0.6-1), unp:amd64 (2.0~pre7+nmu1, automatic), libghc-dpkg-dev:amd64 (0.0.3-4build6), cupt-dbg:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1), libghc-monad-loops-dev:amd64 (0.4.2.1-1, automatic), postgresql-9.4:amd64 (9.4~rc1-1~0ubuntu0.14.10), debootstrap:amd64 (1.0.64), kalternatives:amd64 (0.13-2ubuntu1), xdeb:amd64 (0.6.6), libdatetime-locale-perl:amd64 (0.45-2, automatic), libc6-dbg-armhf-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.105), libmodule-scandeps-perl:amd64 (1.13-1), postfix:amd64 (2.11.1-1), libc6-dbg-powerpc-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.2), cruft:amd64 (0.9.16), libc6-dev-ppc64-powerpc-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.2), libproc-processtable-perl:amd64 (0.50-2), blhc:amd64 (0.04+20140813+gitac2b8ce-1), libc6-dev-ppc64el-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross0.3), pkgbinarymangler:amd64 (121), archdetect-deb:amd64 (1.95ubuntu4), libclass-load-perl:amd64 (0.21-1), libtk-pod-perl:amd64 (0.9942-1, automatic), libc6-dev-armhf-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.105), libc6-powerpc-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.2, automatic), smartpm:amd64 (1.4-2), libclass-data-inheritable-perl:amd64 (0.08-2), vbackup:amd64 (0.1.9-1), libterm-progressbar-simple-perl:amd64 (0.03-1), libtext-autoformat-perl:amd64 (1.669004-1, automatic), libexception-class-perl:amd64 (1.38-1, automatic), dpkg-awk:amd64 (1.2), libmousex-nativetraits-perl:amd64 (1.09-2, automatic), aptitude-doc-en:amd64 (0.6.11-1ubuntu2, automatic), libtk-histentry-perl:amd64 (0.43-3, automatic), equivs:amd64 (2.0.9), libghc-dpkg-doc:amd64 (0.0.3-4build6), libfile-ncopy-perl:amd64 (0.36-1, automatic), cvs-buildpackage:amd64 (5.23), svn-buildpackage:amd64 (0.8.5), epm:amd64 (4.2-6), liblog-log4perl-perl:amd64 (1.43-1ubuntu1, automatic), perl-doc:amd64 (5.20.1-1, automatic), libmime-types-perl:amd64 (2.04-1, automatic), libtext-english-perl:amd64 (1.606-1, automatic), sysconftool:amd64 (0.17-1), advancecomp:amd64 (1.19-1), libdatetime-perl:amd64 (1.10-1build1, automatic), exim4-dev:amd64 (4.84~RC1-3ubuntu2), libuniversal-isa-perl:amd64 (1.20120726-1, automatic), dpkg-cross:amd64 (2.6.11ubuntu1), libconfig-model-dpkg-perl:amd64 (2.051), config-package-dev:amd64 (5.1.2), apt-dpkg-ref:amd64 (5.3.1ubuntu1), ruby-debian:amd64 (0.3.8build3, automatic), libcupt3-dev:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1), libparse-debian-packages-perl:amd64 (0.03-2), apt-show-source:amd64 (0.10), dpkg-sig:amd64 (0.13.1+nmu2), postgresql-common:amd64 (162, automatic), needrestart:amd64 (1.0-1), emacs24:amd64 (24.3+1-4ubuntu1, automatic), libconfig-model-tkui-perl:amd64 (1.344-1, automatic), cupt:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1), libtest-warn-perl:amd64 (0.30-1, automatic), libterm-progressbar-perl:amd64 (2.15-1), libpod-pom-perl:amd64 (0.29-1, automatic), linux-libc-dev-armel-cross:amd64 (3.16.0-23.31cross1.105, automatic), libtest-exception-perl:amd64 (0.32-1, automatic), postgresql-9.4-debversion:amd64 (1.0.7-4), swish++:amd64 (6.1.5-2.2, automatic), optipng:amd64 (0.7.5-1), libc6-armel-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.105), libcupt-common:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1, automatic), emacs24-common-non-dfsg:amd64 (24.3+1-1, automatic), libconfig-auto-perl:amd64 (0.44-1, automatic), localepurge:amd64 (0.7.3.2), libc6-ppc64-powerpc-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.2, automatic), linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross:amd64 (3.16.0-23.31cross0.3, automatic), libconfig-model-perl:amd64 (2.059-1, automatic), postgresql-client-9.4:amd64 (9.4~rc1-1~0ubuntu0.14.10, automatic), libconfig-inifiles-perl:amd64 (2.83-3, automatic), libc6-dbg-armel-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.105), multistrap:amd64 (2.2.0ubuntu2), libcupt3-doc:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1), libdebian-dpkgcross-perl:amd64 (2.6.11ubuntu1, automatic), libcarp-assert-more-perl:amd64 (1.14-1), linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross:amd64 (3.16.0-23.31cross0.11, automatic), libtk-dirselect-perl:amd64 (1.12-1, automatic), libhash-merge-perl:amd64 (0.200-1, automatic), libmodule-find-perl:amd64 (0.12-1), gkdebconf:amd64 (1.2.68ubuntu2), libcupt3-0:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1, automatic), libc6-dev-powerpc-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.2), libfuse-perl:amd64 (0.16.1-1build1, automatic), apt-show-versions:amd64 (0.22.4), libc6-arm64-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross0.11), kbtin:amd64 (1.0.15-1.1+fakesync), libc6-dev-armel-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross1.105), dlocate:amd64 (1.02+nmu3, automatic), smartpm-core:amd64 (1.4-2, automatic), debfoster:amd64 (2.7-2), debian-el:amd64 (35.8ubuntu4), libdpkg-log-perl:amd64 (1.20-2), aptitude-common:amd64 (0.6.11-1ubuntu2, automatic), libc6-dbg-arm64-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross0.11), libsvn-perl:amd64 (1.8.10-1ubuntu2), libc6-dbg-ppc64el-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross0.3), dpkg-ruby:amd64 (0.3.8build3), emacs24-bin-common:amd64 (24.3+1-4ubuntu1, automatic), libtext-diff-perl:amd64 (1.41-1, automatic), libfile-libmagic-perl:amd64 (1.02-1build1), libuniversal-can-perl:amd64 (1.20140328-1, automatic), wajig:amd64 (2.14), libc6-ppc64el-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross0.3, automatic), libc6-dev-arm64-cross:amd64 (2.19-10ubuntu2cross0.11), libmousex-strictconstructor-perl:amd64 (0.02-1, automatic), emacs24-common:amd64 (24.3+1-4ubuntu1, automatic), libcapture-tiny-perl:amd64 (0.24-2), aptitude:amd64 (0.6.11-1ubuntu2), libdatetime-format-strptime-perl:amd64 (1.5600-1), dh-exec:amd64 (0.13), libdatetime-timezone-perl:amd64 (1.73-1+2014f, automatic), libdevel-stacktrace-perl:amd64 (1.3400-1, automatic), libcupt3-0-downloadmethod-curl:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1, automatic), libyaml-perl:amd64 (0.98-1, automatic), dpkg-dev-el:amd64 (35.8ubuntu4), alien:amd64 (8.91), dpkg-www:amd64 (2.54+nmu1), libterm-progressbar-quiet-perl:amd64 (0.31-1), libdebian-installer4:amd64 (0.88ubuntu6, automatic), libghc-monad-loops-prof:amd64 (0.4.2.1-1, automatic), libtext-reform-perl:amd64 (1.20-1, automatic), libparse-recdescent-perl:amd64 (1.967009+dfsg-1, automatic), info2www:amd64 (1.2.2.9-24, automatic), xapt:amd64 (2.2.20), libdpkg-dev:amd64 (1.17.13ubuntu1), libtest-mockobject-perl:amd64 (1.20140408-1, automatic), linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross:amd64 (3.16.0-23.31cross1.2, automatic), libcupt3-0-downloadmethod-wget:amd64 (2.8.2ubuntu1), postgresql-client-common:amd64 (162, automatic), linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross:amd64 (3.16.0-23.31cross1.105, automatic), libghc-bindings-dsl-dev:amd64 (1.0.21-1)
Remove: sensible-mda:amd64 (8.14.4-7), sendmail:amd64 (8.14.4-7), sendmail-bin:amd64 (8.14.4-7), kuvert:amd64 (2.0.12)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  02:43:39

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  02:51:00
Commandline: apt-get install maven openjdk-7-jdk ant sudo software-properties-common python-software-properties xterm
Install: ant:amd64 (1.9.4-1), libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java:amd64 (1.3.1-6, automatic), libjcommander-java:amd64 (1.32-1, automatic), fop:amd64 (1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1, automatic), libcommons-logging-java:amd64 (1.2-1ubuntu1, automatic), libplexus-containers-java:amd64 (1.0~beta3.0.7-7, automatic), libjdom1-java:amd64 (1.1.3-1, automatic), libqdox-java:amd64 (1.12-1build1, automatic), libplexus-container-default-java:amd64 (1.0-alpha-9-stable-1-7, automatic), libeasymock-java:amd64 (3.2+ds-2, automatic), libfop-java:amd64 (1.1.dfsg-2ubuntu1, automatic), libosgi-core-java:amd64 (4.3.1-1, automatic), libcommons-parent-java:amd64 (22-2build1, automatic), libplexus-io-java:amd64 (1.0~alpha5-2, automatic), libmaven-scm-java:amd64 (1.3-5, automatic), libsaxon-java:amd64 (6.5.5-10, automatic), libitext1-java:amd64 (1.4-5, automatic), libxmlgraphics-commons-java:amd64 (1.5-4ubuntu1, automatic), libcommons-codec-java:amd64 (1.9-1, automatic), libhttpcore-java:amd64 (4.3.2-2, automatic), libjsch-java:amd64 (0.1.51-1ubuntu1, automatic), libcommons-jxpath-java:amd64 (1.3-6, automatic), aspectj:amd64 (1.6.12+dfsg-3, automatic), python-software-properties:amd64 (0.94), libplexus-build-api-java:amd64 (0.0.7-1, automatic), junit4:amd64 (4.11-3, automatic), libyaml-snake-java:amd64 (1.12-2, automatic), libcommons-beanutils-java:amd64 (1.9.2-1, automatic), libasm3-java:amd64 (3.3.2-2, automatic), libmodello-java:amd64 (1.1-3, automatic), libwagon-java:amd64 (1.0.0-2ubuntu2, automatic), libcommons-collections3-java:amd64 (3.2.1-7, automatic), libhamcrest-java:amd64 (1.3-5ubuntu1, automatic), libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java:amd64 (1.1-2, automatic), libaether-java:amd64 (1.13.1-2, automatic), libgeronimo-osgi-support-java:amd64 (1.0-2, automatic), libplexus-classworlds2-java:amd64 (2.5.1-2, automatic), liblog4j1.2-java:amd64 (1.2.17-4ubuntu3, automatic), java-wrappers:amd64 (0.1.28, automatic), libcommons-lang-java:amd64 (2.6-3ubuntu2, automatic), libhttpclient-java:amd64 (4.3.4-1, automatic), libclassworlds-java:amd64 (1.1-final-5, automatic), libjackrabbit-java:amd64 (2.3.6-1, automatic), libcommons-io-java:amd64 (2.4-2, automatic), rhino:amd64 (1.7R4-3, automatic), libcommons-cli-java:amd64 (1.2-3ubuntu1, automatic), libplexus-ant-factory-java:amd64 (1.0~alpha2.1-3, automatic), libnetty-java:amd64 (3.2.6.Final-2, automatic), ant-optional:amd64 (1.9.4-1, automatic), junit:amd64 (3.8.2-8build1, automatic), libcommons-vfs-java:amd64 (2.0-3ubuntu1, automatic), libnetbeans-cvsclient-java:amd64 (6.5-2, automatic), libplexus-utils2-java:amd64 (2.0.5-1, automatic), libaopalliance-java:amd64 (20070526-5, automatic), libjline-java:amd64 (1.0-2, automatic), libjetty-java:amd64 (6.1.26-3, automatic), libcommons-jexl2-java:amd64 (2.1.1-2, automatic), libganymed-ssh2-java:amd64 (250-2, automatic), libcommons-net2-java:amd64 (2.2-2, automatic), libsisu-guice-java:amd64 (3.2.2+dfsg-1, automatic), librhino-java:amd64 (1.7R4-3, automatic), libavalon-framework-java:amd64 (4.2.0-9, automatic), libapache-pom-java:amd64 (10-2build1, automatic), libplexus-i18n-java:amd64 (1.0-beta-10-3, automatic), libosgi-compendium-java:amd64 (4.3.0-1, automatic), maven:amd64 (3.0.5-1), libxom-java:amd64 (1.2.10-1, automatic), libservlet2.5-java:amd64 (6.0.41-1, automatic), libmaven2-core-java:amd64 (2.2.1-15, automatic), libregexp-java:amd64 (1.5-3build1, automatic), libplexus-interactivity-api-java:amd64 (1.0-alpha-6-7, automatic), libjaxen-java:amd64 (1.1.6-1ubuntu1, automatic), libplexus-utils-java:amd64 (1.5.15-4, automatic), libbsh-java:amd64 (2.0b4-15, automatic), testng:amd64 (6.8.8-2, automatic), libaspectj-java:amd64 (1.6.12+dfsg-3, automatic), libosgi-foundation-ee-java:amd64 (4.2.0-1, automatic), libjsoup-java:amd64 (1.7.3-1, automatic), libxpp3-java:amd64 (1.1.4c-2build1, automatic), libplexus-interpolation-java:amd64 (1.19-1, automatic), libasync-http-client-java:amd64 (1.6.5-2, automatic), libcglib-java:amd64 (2.2.2+dfsg2-1, automatic), libdoxia-java:amd64 (1.1.4-1ubuntu4, automatic), libmaven-parent-java:amd64 (21-2, automatic), libplexus-cli-java:amd64 (1.2-5, automatic), libdom4j-java:amd64 (1.6.1+dfsg.3-2ubuntu1, automatic), libcdi-api-java:amd64 (1.0-1, automatic), libobjenesis-java:amd64 (1.2+full-3, automatic), libxpp2-java:amd64 (2.1.10-7build1, automatic), libjsch-agent-proxy-java:amd64 (0.0.7-1, automatic), libcommons-httpclient-java:amd64 (3.1-10.2, automatic), libplexus-containers1.5-java:amd64 (1.5.5-6, automatic), libguice-java:amd64 (3.0-3, automatic), libcommons-configuration-java:amd64 (1.10-1, automatic), libxbean-java:amd64 (3.7-6, automatic), libplexus-bsh-factory-java:amd64 (1.0~alpha7-3, automatic), libbsf-java:amd64 (2.4.0-5build1, automatic), libslf4j-java:amd64 (1.7.6-1, automatic), libbatik-java:amd64 (1.7.ubuntu-8ubuntu2, automatic), bsh:amd64 (2.0b4-15, automatic), libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java:amd64 (1.0.1-1fakesync1, automatic), libcommons-digester-java:amd64 (1.8.1-4, automatic), libplexus-classworlds-java:amd64 (1.5.0-5, automatic), libwagon2-java:amd64 (2.6-1.1, automatic), libplexus-cipher-java:amd64 (1.5-4, automatic), libplexus-archiver-java:amd64 (1.2-1, automatic), libsisu-ioc-java:amd64 (2.3.0-5, automatic)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  02:52:24

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  02:58:14
Commandline: apt-get install postgresql-9.2 postgresql-9.2-postgis-2.1 postgresql-9.2-postgis-2.1-scripts postgresql-contrib-9.2 postgresql-client-common
Install: postgresql-9.2:amd64 (9.2.9-1.pgdg14.10+2), libkml0:amd64 (1.3.0~r864+dfsg-1, automatic), postgresql-9.2-postgis-2.1-scripts:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1), postgresql-9.2-postgis-scripts:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1, automatic), libhdf4-0-alt:amd64 (4.2r10-0ubuntu1, automatic), libnetcdfc7:amd64 (4.1.3-7.2, automatic), libossp-uuid16:amd64 (1.6.2-1.5build1, automatic), libepsilon1:amd64 (0.9.2-2, automatic), postgresql-9.2-postgis-2.1:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1), postgresql-contrib-9.2:amd64 (9.2.9-1.pgdg14.10+2), libogdi3.2:amd64 (3.2.0~beta2-7.1, automatic), odbcinst1debian2:amd64 (2.3.1-3, automatic), libdap11:amd64 (3.12.0-1, automatic), postgresql-client-9.2:amd64 (9.2.9-1.pgdg14.10+2, automatic), libspatialite5:amd64 (4.1.1-10, automatic), libdapclient3:amd64 (3.12.0-1, automatic), libgdal1h:amd64 (1.10.1+dfsg-8ubuntu1, automatic), libarpack2:amd64 (3.1.5-3, automatic), libarmadillo4:amd64 (4.400.2+dfsg-1, automatic), libgeos-3.4.2:amd64 (3.4.2-5, automatic), libfreexl1:amd64 (1.0.0g-1, automatic), pgdg-keyring:amd64 (2014.1, automatic), libgeos-c1:amd64 (3.4.2-5, automatic), liburiparser1:amd64 (0.8.0.1-2, automatic), liblwgeom-2.1.5:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1, automatic), odbcinst:amd64 (2.3.1-3, automatic), proj-bin:amd64 (4.8.0-5, automatic)
Upgrade: postgresql-client-common:amd64 (162, 164.pgdg14.10+1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  02:58:46

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  03:00:12
Commandline: apt-get install osm2pgsql
Install: postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1, automatic), postgresql-9.4-postgis-scripts:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1, automatic), osm2pgsql:amd64 (0.84.0-3), postgresql-contrib-9.4:amd64 (9.4.0-1.pgdg14.10+1, automatic), postgis:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1, automatic), postgis-doc:amd64 (2.1.5+dfsg-1~88.git69d0152.pgdg14.10+1, automatic)
Upgrade: postgresql-9.4:amd64 (9.4~rc1-1~0ubuntu0.14.10, 9.4.0-1.pgdg14.10+1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  03:00:27

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  03:02:55
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Upgrade: postgresql-common:amd64 (162, 164.pgdg14.10+1), postgresql-9.4-debversion:amd64 (1.0.7-4, 1.0.7-4.pgdg14.04+1), postgresql-client-9.4:amd64 (9.4~rc1-1~0ubuntu0.14.10, 9.4.0-1.pgdg14.10+1), libpq5:amd64 (9.4~rc1-1~0ubuntu0.14.10, 9.4.0-1.pgdg14.10+1)
Remove: libghc-dpkg-prof:amd64 (0.0.3-4build6), libghc-glib-prof:amd64 (0.12.5.3-1), libghc-dpkg-dev:amd64 (0.0.3-4build6), libghc-monad-loops-dev:amd64 (0.4.2.1-1), ghc-prof:amd64 (7.6.3-19), libghc-glib-dev:amd64 (0.12.5.3-1), libghc-gio-dev:amd64 (0.12.5.3-2), ghc-haddock:amd64 (7.6.3-19), libghc-dpkg-doc:amd64 (0.0.3-4build6), libghc-gstreamer-dev:amd64 (0.12.1.2-3build1), libghc-mtl-dev:amd64 (2.1.2-4), libghc-glib-doc:amd64 (0.12.5.3-1), libghc-gio-doc:amd64 (0.12.5.3-2), needrestart:amd64 (1.0-1), libghc-gstreamer-doc:amd64 (0.12.1.2-3build1), libghc-transformers-prof:amd64 (0.3.0.0-5), libghc-utf8-string-prof:amd64 (0.3.7-3), ghc:amd64 (7.6.3-19), libghc-mtl-prof:amd64 (2.1.2-4), libghc-gstreamer-prof:amd64 (0.12.1.2-3build1), libghc-gio-prof:amd64 (0.12.5.3-2), libghc-monad-loops-prof:amd64 (0.4.2.1-1), libghc-transformers-dev:amd64 (0.3.0.0-5), libghc-utf8-string-dev:amd64 (0.3.7-3), ghc-doc:amd64 (7.6.3-19), libghc-bindings-dsl-dev:amd64 (1.0.21-1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  03:03:05

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  03:06:34
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Install: ansible-doc:amd64 (1.7.2+dfsg-1), python-yaml:amd64 (3.11-1, automatic), ansible:amd64 (1.7.2+dfsg-1), python-jinja2:amd64 (2.7.3-1, automatic), python-selinux:amd64 (2.3-1build1, automatic)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  03:06:37

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  03:29:08
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Install: augeas-doc:amd64 (1.2.0-0ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  03:29:09

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  04:15:25
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Install: libtcnative-1:amd64 (1.1.31-1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  04:15:26

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  04:22:20
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Remove: sendmail-cf:amd64 (8.14.4-7), libfile-slurp-perl:amd64 (9999.19-4), libbsd-dev:amd64 (0.7.0-2), libnet-server-mail-perl:amd64 (0.21-1), libnet-smtps-perl:amd64 (0.03-1), sendmail-base:amd64 (8.14.4-7)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  04:22:25

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  04:56:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get dist-upgrade
Install: libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu2, automatic)
Upgrade: spring-common:amd64 (96.0+dfsg-2, 98.0~14.10~ppa6), spring:amd64 (96.0+dfsg-2, 98.0~14.10~ppa6)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  04:56:37

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  08:11:02
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get build-dep libtcnative-1
Install: libsctp-dev:amd64 (1.0.16+dfsg-2, automatic), libapr1-dev:amd64 (1.5.1-2)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  08:11:06

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  08:13:48
Commandline: apt-get -y install libowfat-dev
Install: libowfat-dev:amd64 (0.29-4), libowfat0:amd64 (0.29-4, automatic)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  08:13:55

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  10:25:43
Commandline: apt-get -y install libjansson-dev
Install: libjansson-dev:amd64 (2.6-1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  10:25:45

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  10:37:46
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Install: nvidia-340-uvm:amd64 (340.65-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  10:38:58

Start-Date: 2014-12-30  10:52:23
Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
Remove: ansible:amd64 (1.7.2+dfsg-1)
End-Date: 2014-12-30  10:52:55
```

The system booted fine multiple times after fresh installation. In case someone has an idea which package might cause the described issues, I can remove and reinstall it in order verify.

Adding kernel boot parameter `nomodeset` doesn't change anything, i.e. neither the issue nor the poor logging.

Comment: To your edit: this is defenetly  wrong. `NetworkManager ` is not starting because the network is not configured completly. In fact you can start `NetworkManager` after login using `sudo NetworkManager` (this worked on my PC). I think the error is not in `init.d` but in `ifup`, wich uses the _/etc/network/interfaces_ file.

Comment: @LittleByBlue How to configure the network so that `NetworkManager` (it's `init.d` service is called `network-manager`) can start at boot? Issueing `sudo service network-manager start` is what I have to do and do after login. The error can't be related to `/etc/network/interfaces` because it contains nothing but the content in ATAKAMA's answer below. I'm not using `ifconfig` (including `ifup`) approach (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/1786/what-is-the-difference-between-network-manager-and-ifconfig-ifup-etc for details on differences)

Comment: I think `ifup` is used at every boot. I selved the problem at first by making a little shellscript, wich was called at boot, wich started `NetworkManager` after the boot using `anacron`. This is in fact just making the symptoms invisible, but does not solve your real problem. I would try to boot without the option `quiet`, to watch what happens.

Comment: `quiet` has never been a boot parameter in my case (I think it's because of mainline kernel (3.17.x). The messages "waiting for network..." just appear out of nowhere.

Comment: try `nomodeset` or something wich causes the bootstrap to tell you what is going on :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first ensure that the `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains at least the loopback interface configuration:

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

Next, if you have any `auto` stanzas and the interfaces might not be available at boot, you can replace `auto` with `allow-hotplug` to prevent upstart from waiting for them to be brought up (i.e. replace `auto eth0` with `allow-hotplug eth0`).

Finally, the brute-force approach would be to comment out or modify the sleep timers in `/etc/init/failsafe.conf`, but this is obviously not recommended as the file might be modified by any subsequent upstart update.

Comment: Interesting, the entry was missing, but after adding it the issue persists. Modifying the timer in `/etc/init/failsafe.conf` would just hide the symptoms, but not cure the desease. Who would I retrieve knowledge from changing timer values? I only handle `lo` in the `interfaces` file (thanks to your answer ;)) and the rest should be done with network-manager like before the issue occured.

Comment: ATAKAMA 's answer is in fact correct. I had the same issue with an `auto` set up wlan dongle.